# How do i change the default language in Symfony to english

Tags: symfony

How may I change my default language from nl_NL to English. So from now when my data save in database will list in English  . Please can some help me as I'm new in Symfony:

[image]

Comment: can someone help to know me fast how to change language from nl_NL to US english ?

Comment: This is not clear: where are that texts coming from? If they're coming from database, it's not enough to change your current locale to english, you'll also need to define translations.

Comment: @MassimilianoArione  yes , i have explored more and found these values coming from database now how may i set translations ? in it to show them in English ?

Comment: You can refer to official documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Answer (score 1):

Default locale setting:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
  default_locale: en
```

And `php app/console c:c` after introducing configuration change.

But I really do not know what is `Event` and how you are saving it to `DB`?

Comment: framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: en }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"  this is what i have used and in my parameter.yml  locale is en

Comment: So you default locale is `en`